# Golang - Sum of an [...]interface{}

Tags: go, types, interface, type-assertion

I have created a generic data structure, with a name and a generic array in Golang.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type NamedArray struct {
  Name string
  values []interface{}
}

func main() {
  data := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
  interfaced_data := make([]interface{}, len(data))
  for i, v := range data{
    interfaced_data[i] = v
  }
  int_arr := NamedArray{Name: "Int Array", values: interfaced_data}
  fmt.Println(int_arr)
  // fmt.Println(int_arr.Sum()) -- uncomment to run Sum

  data_float := [...]float64{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}
  interfaced_data_float := make([]interface{}, len(data_float))
  for i, v := range data_float{
    interfaced_data_float[i] = v
  }
  float_arr := NamedArray{Name: "Float Array", values: interfaced_data_float}
  fmt.Println(float_arr)
  // fmt.Println(int_arr.Sum()) -- uncomment to run Sum
}
```

Now I want to define a method which allows me to sum all the values in the array. I know that they are numeric (though whether they are `int` or `float` is dependant on context) but I am having some serious trouble.

```
func (arr NamedArray) Sum() interface{} {
  data := arr.values
  sum := 0
  for i, v := range data {
    sum += v
  }
  return sum
}
```

I can't seem to make this work, though. When I uncomment lines 18 and 27 (`fmt.Println(int_arr.Sum()` and `fmt.Println(int_arr.Sum()`) and try to run the code I get

```
34:9: invalid operation: sum += v (mismatched types int and interface {})
```

During compilation.

Does anyone know how to add generic types, given we know that they are numeric?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to check the actual type and handle the different cases separately. Note that there are a lot of numeric types in Go so many cases to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+` operator is not defined on values of type `interface{}`. You have to get a value of type `int` out of the `interface{}` values before you can work with it as a number.

For that, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). See this example:

```
s := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, "invalid"}

sum := 0
for _, v := range s {
    if i, ok := v.(int); ok {
        sum += i
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not int:", v)
    }
}
fmt.Println("Sum:", sum)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-EPGDkY1ysY)):

```
Not int: invalid
Sum: 6
```

The above example only handles `int` numbers, and nothing else. If you want to "support" multiple number types, a more convenient way would be to use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

```
s := []interface{}{1, int32(2), int8(3), "invalid"}

sum := 0
for _, v := range s {
    switch i := v.(type) {
    case int:
        sum += i
    case int32:
        sum += int(i)
    case int8:
        sum += int(i)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Not int:", v)
    }
}
fmt.Println("Sum:", sum)
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HKToK4ZZJhI).